# Saving desktopCapturer to video file from Electron app

Tags: javascript, blob, electron, getusermedia, mediastream

Basing on [electron api](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/desktop-capturer.md) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753288/saving-desktopcapturer-to-video-file-in-electron) I'm trying to save recorded user screen to .webm file in videos folder in root app folder.

Actually it's almost working because it save .webm file but the file which is saved is empty, it weigh 0B.. I don't know what I'm missing here.

[image: example file is 0 bytes]

So it looks like it's somehow not recording correctly because file is empty..

**edit** when debbuging I discovered that recording is probably working correctly because blobs which I console log has value inside, after `toArrayBuffer` my blob no longer has value inside.

Code is:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var fs = require('fs');
    var { desktopCapturer } = require('electron');
    var recorder, blobs = [];

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('loggedScreen', Controller);

    Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function Controller($scope) {

        var startRecord = function () {
            console.log('started');
            desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, function(error) {
                if (error) throw error;
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        mandatory: {
                            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                            minWidth: 1280,
                            maxWidth: 1280,
                            minHeight: 720,
                            maxHeight: 720
                        }
                    }
                }, handleStream, handleError);
                return;
            });
        };

        function handleError(err) {
            console.log('something went wrong but it shouldnt');
        }

        function handleStream(stream) {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            blobs = [];
            recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
                blobs.push(event.data);
            };
            recorder.start();
        }

        function toArrayBuffer(blob, cb) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function() {
                var arrayBuffer = this.result;
                cb(arrayBuffer);
            };
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        }

        function toBuffer(ab) {
            var buffer = new Buffer(ab.byteLength);
            var arr = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.byteLength; i++) {
                buffer[i] = arr[i];
            }
            return buffer;
        }

        function stopRecording() {
            recorder.stop();
            console.log(blobs); // 300k bytes
            toArrayBuffer(new Blob(blobs, {type: 'video/webm'}), function(ab) {
                console.log(ab); // 0 bytes
                var buffer = toBuffer(ab);
                var file = `./videos/example.webm`;
                fs.writeFile(file, buffer, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Failed to save video ' + err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Saved video: ' + file);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        startRecord();
        setTimeout(function() {
            // stop recording after 7sec
            stopRecording();
        }, 7000);
    }
})();
```

`startRecord()` function is executed immediately, it also `console.log` started as expected just after hitting this controller.

`stopRecording()` function is executed after 7 second correctly, it `console.log('Saved video: ' + file);` just fine.

Then I go to my just created videos folder I open my saved **example.webm** file and it's empty.

It doesn't print any error in console.

---

- I `consoled.log(blobs)` after stoping recorder in `stopRecording()` function to see if it's actually Blob.
- I `console.log(ab)` inside `toArrayBuffer(new Blob(blobs, {type: 'video/webm'}), function(ab) {})` callback.

[image: screenshot of consoled things]

I've got behaviour as `blobs` contains value when `ab` not.

---

I really can't solve it myself, looking for answer I create [demo repository](https://bitbucket.org/dopeCode/recordinissue/src/master/) with minimal reproduced example just clone it to see behaviour for your own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `recorder.stop()` will run as follows: ([from MediaRecorder docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/stop))

> When the stop() method is invoked, the UA queues a task that runs the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. If `MediaRecorder.state` is "inactive", raise a DOM `InvalidState` error and terminate these steps. If the `MediaRecorder.state` is not "inactive", continue on to the next step.
> 2. Set the `MediaRecorder.state` to "inactive" and stop capturing media.
> 3. Raise a `dataavailable` event containing the Blob of data that has been gathered.
> 4. Raise a `stop` event.

In your case you don't wait up the `stop` event, so `dataavailable` will fill `blobs` only after you started the file saving method.

You have to restructure `stopRecording` to ensure recorded data is available. For example:

```
function stopRecording () {
  const save = () => {
    ...
  }
  recorder.onstop = save
  recorder.stop()
}
```

Comment: Did you test it on example repo? I'll be able to test it around 20 oclock

Comment: I've tested it and the result file had reasonable size. (that's all i checked)

Comment: Yeah it's working correctly bruh! Is there some way to make movie in better quality? I'll give you bounty anway but just asking ( I can do this in 7 hours)

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I don't work with these classes, just was curious :)